# _CastError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast)

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to get data from a nested collection in my fireabase which is inside 'user'->'discounts' and getting image download URL from same collection in 'user'->'images' I'm trying to get is according to a specific currentUser.uid and I'm getting this cast error.

```
body: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
    future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('user')
        .doc(currentUser!.uid)
        .collection('discounts')
        .doc(currentUser!.uid)
        .get(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'No Data.');
      }
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
      Map<String, dynamic>? data =
          snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      return ListView(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => MerchantDiscounts(
                    id: '${data['docid']}',
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              width: 370.0,
              height: 200.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                color: Colors.black26,
              ),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: NetworkImage(
                          data['downloadURL'],
                        ),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        colorFilter: const ColorFilter.mode(
                          Colors.black38,
                          BlendMode.darken,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(320, 0, 0, 0),
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        deleteDiscount(data['docid']);
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.delete_forever_rounded),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      iconSize: 35.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      '${data['productName']}',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Text(
                      '${data['discount']}',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 80,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 160, 8, 8),
                    child: Text(
                      '${data['category']}',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  ),
```

[This is the Image of the collection in my fireabase database from which I'm trying to get data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNzH9.png)

[The image of nested collection from which I'm getting 'discounts' data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1a4G.png)

I'm new to flutter and I searched and tried to apply different fixes but I'm getting this error everytime. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should also check if snapshot.data and snapshot.data.data() is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it seems you're typecasting a nulluble type as a non-nullable type. Removing the **?** after the first Map<String, dynamic>? should work. Try replacing this

```
Map<String, dynamic>? data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

With this

```
var data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
```